# How to convert selected polygons to their boundary edges?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, faces, edges

For example I've selected this face
[image]

Then I need to convert to edge (border of selected faces)
[image]

Is there any way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a menu item for this: *Header > Select > Select Loops > Select Boundary Loop*. Candidate for a shortcut, if you use it a lot.